# finding largest and smallest numbers in an array

Tags: visual-c++

i have to find the max and min value in array of random numbers... here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void populateArray();
int findMin();
int findMax();
int computeTotal();
int arr[50];
int small, big;
void main()
{
    big = small = arr[0];
    populateArray();
    findMin();
    findMax();
    computeTotal();
    system("pause");
}
void populateArray()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 1000;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int findMin()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < small)
        {
            small = arr[i];
        }
        cout << "The smallest number is " << small << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
int findMax()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > big)
        {
            big = arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "The biggest number is " << big << endl;
    return 0;
}
int computeTotal()
{
    int sum = 0;
    sum = big + small;
    cout << "Total= " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is that it does not display the minimum and maximum value from the array... it displays minimum value 0 and max 995 which are not included even in the array..
any help??

Comment: `big = small = arr[0];` What is the value of `arr[0]` there?

Comment: it is just initialized. plz help me to improve this code.

Comment: Also, in `findMin` the `cout` needs to be outside the `for` loop.